# Advanced generic contraints, only allow contents of U dependent on what T is?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Can anyone help with a signature for generics. I currently have this, and it works great!.

Although I would like to add some constraints, but the constraints should be constrained depending on the types of another type.

```
  async publish<T>(exchange: Exchange, routingKey: RoutingKey, message: T, options?: amqplib.Options.Publish) {
    return this.amqpConnection.publish(exchange, routingKey, message, options)
  }
```

I would like to put a constraint if possible on RoutingKey and also on "T".

So T is the message but the constraint would be dependent on what the RoutingKey was set to.

And if possible the RoutingKey would be dependent on what Exchange was set to.

So for example, here are some types.

```
// 2 types of exchanges.
export enum Exchange {
  BscDexPancakeswap = "bsc-dex-pancakeswap",
  PolygonQuickwap = "polygon-dex-quickswap",
}

export enum RoutingKey {
  PendingTx = "pending-tx", // this can be available to all Exchange
  PendingTxHash = "pending-tx-hash", // this can be available to all Exchange
  BridgeChain = "bridge-chain", // this should be only a valid choice when Excahnge is set to PolygonQuickswap
}

// This is the "T" being passed into publish

export interface TxHashMsg { // valid for any Routing Key
  txHash: string
}

export interface TxMsg { // valid for any Routing Key
  tx: string
}

export interface BridgeMsg { // valid for any Only Routing Key = BridgeChain
  bridgeId: string
}
```

To put it in simple terms, this should throw a type error, because routingKey is wrong

```
this.messageBrokerService.publish<BridgeMsg>(Exchange.BscDexPancakeswap, RoutingKey.PendingTx, tx)
```

and this also because the Exchange is wrong

```
this.messageBrokerService.publish<BridgeMsg>(Exchange.BscDexPancakeswap, RoutingKey.BridgeChain, tx)
```

This is valid because Exchange is correct and RoutingKey is correct and Message is correct - all those constraints that I talked about above.

```
this.messageBrokerService.publish<BridgeMsg>(Exchange.PolygonQuickwap, RoutingKey.BridgeChain, tx)
```

This is quite a mouthful, I was wondering if it's possible and how easy it could be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the structures? I am thinking of embedding the `routingKey` into the message structures.

Comment: Yep, those types belong to me. So yes, its possible. I went with a Enum because it was pretty simple what I needed.. They are literally key:value pairs..

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wOzeMW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you’re trying to do does not look very natural. Perhaps, if you have the possibility to change the structure of your messages, would something like this do it?

```
interface Message<T, U = RoutingKey> {
  readonly routingKey: U;
  readonly content: T;
}

export type TxHashMessage = Message<{
  readonly txHash: string;
}>;

export type TxMsg = Message<{
  readonly tx: string;
}>;

export type BridgeMsg = Message<{
  readonly bridgeId: string;
}, RoutingKey.BridgeChain>;

function publish<T, U, M extends Message<T, U>>(msg: M) {
  // ...
};
```

This way you will get type-safety at message-level, not the publish function. You can check out a working example (including a type error) [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9mALgSxAcwNLAJ5QN4BQUxUACqACapoAqAHlALxQDkADpdQLSJ0sA0REgCEATsgppgAYQAWAQ1RNWAI3GTgXAMYLUAggF8CBVImCiAZvK3AoAWWABnR-KkAeGvygBVZfCTUWNgAfPhCosDyFHAgADa4oggo6EEAXD4A3OGR0XG4WjFmIIjpNFlGBMB0bHCiiFCI2BxQ9AAS8o6yDs6utszdLu6ExBFRMfENdO2d6Y6I4ujlwVmV1bX1jc30do5oygO9bsNQo7kTvLPz1EsrVTV1DU22YhJSO3v9ToPAR9ljeVA1K9gABJCiXBZocpefzJTA4AB0Lw0ckUIGWxgsYBAWhQMSgbDAKliyE6Hi83i8digVSKFEc9i+h08PmCwQAFBBduk7ABKMIkKAFECOOCxYAI2JwNCc3YIxIBFI4XnlYzCuaTaZdJlSUpTDranpSZTHEZJQI4dKwi3YJHqKSo1CCQXCoolAWCki8LXpFjE+T6QUGQQGLKE4mk2Ts70Gg5SFVqmIagDuiXQyLe3KgGeA7xNQjNivh2Ct5qVtvIICo6HozpIrtA7tNnqBGjBvv9gZIRlDBHDJM67NTMTQOfeKqAA).

Also note that `Message` base interface is not exported (which you could decide to change, of course). However, the type aliases are, which would ideally encourage the user to use those only. This depends on your specific context, but I thought it was worth to mention.